# How do you pass text back from a Action Extension?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an Action Extension for iOS that simply manipulates text. Currently, the only working way of passing the transformed text is to copy it to the UIPasteboard, but I've seen a few examples, and read through as little documentation there is, to find a "solution".

I've followed as many examples as I can, and this is the only way I've found:

```
func extensionItem(with text: String) -> NSExtensionItem {
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(item: text as NSSecureCoding?, typeIdentifier: kUTTypeText as String)
    let item = NSExtensionItem()
    item.attachments = [itemProvider]
    return item
}
```

Although no app seems to support reading it.

The working version I've seen in the wild is in Workflow. If you create a workflow that is just one action - change case to uppercase, you can use the share sheet from a text selection, it will return an NSExtensionItem, and the source app will replace the text with the new content.

I'm not sure if this is general app behaviour, or only some support this. But for some reason I seem to be doing something wrong.

The only hint I've found, is that in the NSExtensionItem that comes back from Workflow, the content is actually a URL to a .txt (located somewhere), with the new content inside that.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

There seems to be a lack of documentation about this from Apple.